# Streams with express and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, events, stream

I'm integrating a payment solution into my application. The difficulty I'm having is that I'd like to send a response to the customer based on a change in my mongo database. Let me explain. When I make a payment, the status of my request is initially pending and when the payment is validated, the integrator calls my callback to change the status of this transaction. It's at this point, when status is set to success, that I'd like to send a success response.

To do this, my api would have to listen to my database every time, and when status changes to validated, it would automatically send my response. How can I implement this?
[image: my actual code]